# Insert fitted values from an R model into MySQL table

Tags: mysql, r

I'd like to calculate the fitted values for a model fit in R using `glm` on data in a MySQL table and pipe the result back into that table, how could I do that?

Comment: I thought it might be interessing as often ppl either know MySQL _or_ R

Comment: Do you want to save the predicted values? The regression coefficients?

Comment: I want to save the predicted (fitted) values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# preparation
library("RMySQL")
con <- dbConnect(MySQL(), user="####", pass="###", host="127.0.0.1", db="###")
on.exit(dbDisconnect(con))

# fetching the data and calculating fit    
tab <- dbGetQuery(con,"SELECT ID, dep, indep1, indep2 FROM table WHERE !(ISNULL(ID) OR ISNULL(dep) OR ISNULL(indep1) OR ISNULL(indep2))")
regression = glm(tab$dep ~ tab$indep1 + tab$indep2, gaussian)

# preparing data for insertion
insert <- data.frame(tab$ID, fitted.values(regression)
colnames(insert) <- c('ID', 'dep')

# table hassle (inserting data, combining with previous table, deleting old and fitresult renaming combined back to original name
if (dbExistsTable(con, '_result') {
    dbRemoveTable(con, '_result');
}
dbWriteTable(con, '_result', insert)
dbSendQuery(con, 'CREATE TABLE temporary SELECT table.*, _result.dep FROM table LEFT JOIN result USING (ID)')
dbRemoveTable(con, 'table')
dbRemoveTable(con, '_result')
dbSendQuery(con, 'RENAME TABLE temporary TO table')
```